# Silent / unattended ansible playbook execution on Windows VM

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible

I have created a playbook to install/upgrade a third party vendor application on a Windows VM. I am using the ansible tower to execute the playbook. I used the below script to upgrade

```
- name: Run the installer to upgrade the app
  win_shell: powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -noninteractive -nologo -file '.\Install.ps1'
  args:
    chdir: "{{ app_path }}"
```

I wasn't able to proceed on the installation. While trying it manually, I have noticed that there were 2 db migration script execution related pop-up windows appearing (triggered by the anti-virus as it is an execution of an exe file in middle of the installer script - due to security reasons). I had to select 'Allow this file' option to continue the execution, while trying it manually.

I was told by the product vendor that I need to add the folders where the script is available as an exception in anti-virus to prevent the pop-up. But I would like to know - is there an option for silent / unattended execution of the scripts on Windows VM in ansible - which will directly take care of allowing the execution? I heard about -s in RHEL VMs; but couldn't find any options for Windows VMs.

Appreciate your help!!

Comment: What would you expect from such an option? That it automagically responds *yes* or *no* to arbitrary prompts? Your current setup seems to require human interaction. So either configure your AV to not prompt for things or whitelist your software/folder so that there is no need for your AV to prompt.

Comment: Yes, I would like to see if there are any options to handle via ansible scripts other than whitelisting the folder.

Comment: I guess it depends in why the prompt appears. It a signature based detection? Is this message by av or by os? More details about message please.

Comment: Take the signature of the Install.ps1 script with something like `Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 -Path <...>.\install.ps1` and add it as an exclusion in your AV. Usually when adding exceptions (but you didn't mention which security solution is deployed so it's only guess here), you can enable options like "child processes" so the "pop-up" that you can will be allowed. 
You can also create this  same exception through a pretask (with an api call for instance, and that's depend of your security solution(s?)) and remove it later.

Comment: Note that each time your install.ps1 is changing, you will have to take the new hash (or include the hash calc in the pretask but that's not very secure)

Comment: It was captured by Symantec AV.  At this moment, as suggested by the vendor, I am proceeding with adding the folder in exception list - by the AV team.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code snippet

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Install Chocolatey
      win_shell: |
        Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
      args:
        executable: powershell.exe
      register: install_choco
      changed_when: install_choco.rc == 0
      failed_when: install_choco.rc != 0
      ignore_errors: yes

    - name: Install Ansible
      win_shell: choco install ansible -y
      args:
        executable: powershell.exe
      register: install_ansible
      changed_when: install_ansible.rc == 0
      failed_when: install_ansible.rc != 0
      ignore_errors: yes

    - name: Install Git
      win_shell: choco install git -y
      args:
        executable: powershell.exe
      register: install_git
      changed_when: install_git.rc == 0
      failed_when: install_git.rc != 0
      ignore_errors: yes
```